# 42P07: Error while updating Postgre Entity Framework Core database

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to update the database using the EntityFramework migration, but this error crashes. I started looking at what they write on this issue, but everywhere the same thing, that do not use **EnsureCreated**  in a startup and that's it. I don't have anything like that in a startup, here's the code in a startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUserModel, IdentityRole>(
                options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false
                )
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Well, of course, adding authorization, adding providers, and so on. But as soon as I try to start the migration, the error falls below.

Who faced this problem or knows how to solve it, please tell me.

Thank you very much for your answers!

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE "AspNetRoles" (
          "Id" text NOT NULL,
          "Name" character varying(256) NULL,
          "NormalizedName" character varying(256) NULL,
          "ConcurrencyStamp" text NULL,
          CONSTRAINT "PK_AspNetRoles" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
      );
Failed executing DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE "AspNetRoles" (
    "Id" text NOT NULL,
    "Name" character varying(256) NULL,
    "NormalizedName" character varying(256) NULL,
    "ConcurrencyStamp" text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_AspNetRoles" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P07: отношение "AspNetRoles" уже существует
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|194_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
  Exception data:
    Severity: ОШИБКА
    SqlState: 42P07
    MessageText: отношение "AspNetRoles" уже существует
    File: d:\pginstaller.auto\postgres.windows-x64\src\backend\catalog\heap.c
    Line: 1094
    Routine: heap_create_with_catalog
42P07: отношение "AspNetRoles" уже существует
```

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to be a "duplicated relation" in Postgres. This means that you are probably trying to recreate a database table that already exists. You should double check your migrations - it's possible that for some reason it's trying to recreate a database that already exists.

Another reason would be some sort of unsync'ing between your migration and the database - maybe someone else created the table manually, for instance?